# Blender dev build question

Tags: windows, installation

On https://builder.blender.org/download/ there are 2 version available for download:

***non-stable build*** and 
***Experimental Build Branch by VS 2015*** .

What does this mean and what are the differences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A build considered as not stable is a version in developpement. They have new functionnalities/changes that still need to be tested, or contains known bug that will be fixed before official releases.

An Experimental Build Branch, as said in the description are build with another compiler than the "usual" one. They should be stable (release 2.78) but you never now what can appen using a compiler that wasn't used for tests.

If you have no reason to use one of them, use the [official release](https://www.blender.org/download/)